# List out of range paradox

Tags: python

For somewhat reason I got stuck in a simple logic python. In C++ this would be much easier

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 100
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    lamb = [0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8]
    y = []
    for index,value in lamb:
        y.append(index,value,n)
```

When I did the code above it got rejected (out of list range) while using the same logic below, the code seems to work.

What's different in Python?

```
    y.append(meanwait(x[0], lamb[0], n))
    y.append(meanwait(x[1], lamb[1], n))
    y.append(meanwait(x[2], lamb[2], n))
    y.append(meanwait(x[3], lamb[3], n))
```

Comment: Those 2 code samples are not the same

Comment: The error I got is not out of range but `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: I think what you wanted is `for index,value in (lamb)`

Comment: How is  it related to C++?

Comment: append takes exactly one argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for index,value in lamb` will not work because it tries to unpack `index,value` from floats such as `0.2` where it expects a 2-tuple. You will get the same error (which is not the one you posted) with:

```
for item in lamb:
    index,value = item
```

What you want is:

```
for index,value in enumerate(lamb):
```

And to make it clear what's going on, insert this before the loop and look at the output:

```
print list(enumerate(lamb))
```

For more info, look up tuple unpacking and enumerate.

Edit: I notice now that you don't seem to want the actual index, but rather the matching value in `x` (which is 1 more), in which case replace `zip` with enumerate in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`zip` function may help you.

```
def meanwait(a,b,c):
    # I don't know the behavior
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 100
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    lamb = [0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8]
    y = []
    for (index,value) in zip(x,lamb):
        y.append(meanwait(index,value,n))
```

Comment: Thanks! Thank helped!